# ClojureScript file preloader - function or pattern to emulate promise?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, promise, clojurescript

I'm trying to create a file preloader within ClojureScript. My idea was a pattern like this:

```
(def urls (atom[]))
(def loaded-resources (atom []))
(def all-resources (promise))

(defn loading-callback []
  (if (= (count urls) (count loaded-resources))
    (deliver all-resources loaded-resources)))

;; fill urls array
;; start ajax-loading with loading-callback on success
```

So my main function could go on until it would require the resources and then wait for them, which works well in Clojure.

Unfortunately, promises don't exist in ClojureScript, so how can I work around that issue? There's [promesa](https://funcool.github.io/promesa/latest/) bringing promises to CLJS based on core.async channels, but it only allows future-like promises that wait for a single function to execute which won't suffice my needs (at least in the way I've been thinking about it yesterday...).

Any suggestions to solve this issue? Maybe use a completely different pattern? I want to keep the code as simple as possible to convince people in my team to try out CLJ/S.

**EDIT:**

After Alan's second idea:

```
(def urls (atom[]))
(def loaded-resources (atom []))

(defn loading-callback [data]
  (swap! loaded-resources conj data))

(defn load! [post-loading-fn]
  (add-watch loaded-resources :watch-loading
    (fn [_ _ _ cur]
      (if (= (count cur) (count @urls)) (post-loading-fn))))
  ;; init ajax loading
  )

(defn init []
;; fill urls array
  (load! main))

(main []
  (do-terrific-stuff @loaded-resources))
```

Meanwhile I had tried to use `core.async`

```
(def urls (atom []))
(def loaded-resources (atom []))
(def resource-chan (chan))

(defn loading-callback [data]
  (go (>! resource-chan data)))

;; fill url array from main

(load! []
  ;; init ajax loading
  (go-loop []
    (when-not (= (count @loaded-resources) (count @urls))
      (swap! loaded-resources conj (<! resource-chan))
      (recur)))
```

Not sure which version is better.

Comment: Use `goog.Promise` and then shove them in `goog.Promise.all`

Comment: Interesting suggestion, as the google framework gets imported anyways... I didn't try it yet, but at the moment I stuck to the idea @alan-thompson gave me and used a watcher that executs a post-loading hook when everything is done. It works quite well for my needs.

Comment: It's also a bad idea since you're dealing with mutable state and rely on your logic being bug free. This is exactly what `goog.Promise.all` was made for. Even javascript coders would understand that code. It's a very common pattern in frontend development!

Comment: Also don't forget error handling, what happens if one of the URLs fails? Do you wait forever? Does your error propagate properly? `Promise.all` handles this properly.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 approaches.

1. Change `all-resources` to another atom, initialized at nil.  Poll it 2x-5x/sec until it is not nil and has the "delivered" result.
2. Use `add-watch` to register a callback function to execute when the value is changed. This takes the place of blocking until the value is delivered. It is described here:  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch

They show a good example:

```
(def a (atom {}))

(add-watch a :watcher
  (fn [key atom old-state new-state]
    (prn "-- Atom Changed --")
    (prn "key" key)
    (prn "atom" atom)
    (prn "old-state" old-state)
    (prn "new-state" new-state)))

(reset! a {:foo "bar"})

;; "-- Atom Changed --"
;; "key" :watcher
;; "atom" #<Atom@4b020acf: {:foo "bar"}>
;; "old-state" {}
;; "new-state" {:foo "bar"}
;; {:foo "bar"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, @Alan The first approach is no different from comparing the number of delivered resources to the number of requested ones, except that a third atom stores the result, or am I wrong? Using watchers occured to me, too, but they won't block the main thread. I could, of course, initialise loading, add a watcher, then finish the main method. The watcher then would check for completeness and call a function containing the rest of the main thread after loading...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your load resource function returns a channel (like cljs-http/get).

In clj, all you need to do is hold on to them to do a "wait-all".

```
(let [cs  (doall (map load-resource urls))   ;; initiate the get
      ...                                    ;; other initialisation
      res (map <!! cs)]                      ;; wait-all for the resources
  (do-other-things res))
```

In cljs, you can accumulate the responses before you continue:

```
(go
    (let [res (atom [])]
      (doseq [c cs]
        (swap! res conj (<! c)))
      (do-other-things @res)))
```

Comment: There is no `<!!` in cljs

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a single threaded environment so there is no blocking wait.

If you wish to request multiple resources and continue iff they have all been served, I do recommend using core.async and especially [pipeline-async](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pipeline-async). It has a knob to finetune the parallelism of asynchronous requests. Here is idiomatic ClojureScript code to achieve what you want:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [cljs.core.async :refer [chan take! put! pipeline-async] 
                             :as async]))

(defn load-resources [urls on-resources]
  (let [urls-ch (chan (count urls))
        resources-ch (chan)]
    ;; Create pipeline:
    (pipeline-async 10 ;; have at most 10 requests in flight at
                       ;; the same time, finetune as desired
                    resources-ch 
                    (fn [url done-ch]
                      ;; Pseudo code:
                      (request-resource 
                       url
                       (fn [loaded-resource]
                         (put! done-ch loaded-resource))))
                    urls-ch)
    ;; Eagerly aggregate result until results-ch closes, then call back:
    (take! (async/into [] resources-ch) on-resources)
    ;; Start the party by putting all urls onto urls-ch 
    ;; and then close it:
    (async/onto-chan urls-ch urls)))
```